# Solving for the inverse of $f(n)=\frac{2}{5}n^{2.5}+\frac{1}{2}n^{1.5}+\frac{1}{8}n^{0.5}+\frac{1}{1920}n^{-1.5}$

Tags: inverse-function

$$f(n)=\frac{2}{5}n^{2.5}+\frac{1}{2}n^{1.5}+\frac{1}{8}n^{0.5}+\frac{1}{1920}n^{-1.5}$$

the inverse I need is for all positive integers.

Can someone either tell me how to get this functions inverse, or just give it to me?

All I know about finding inverse is that I'd need just to get $n$ by itself, but have no clue how to go about doing that, if it's even possible. Though if it's not, is there a way to have excel use this formula as if it's already in it's inverse? (I know that addition would be better on another community, but won't change community unless told that the inverse of this is impossible.)

Comment: It's better if you use the MathJax sintax"

Comment: I was about to do so, but have never used it before, so was figuring it out, when projectilemotion did it for me, but thx @Edonbrayn & projectilemotion

Comment: There is no inverse... try graphing it on desmos.com/calculator. There are multiple x-values for a single y-value. Perhaps you want the inverse on a specific interval.

Comment: See $\mathbf{3.6.25}$ in
[A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_16.htm).

Comment: no clue how to interpret that @FelixMarin

Comment: It's just a starting point. I'll use $z = n^{0.5}$ instead. The last term does not agree with my previous link. I became aware of that after I wrote my previous comment.